# gstreamer-1.0, RTSP H264 stream and shared memory

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I'm trying to write RTSP stream in shared memory, and then write it in .mkv file.

I use this command to write stream in .mkv file directly:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.88.248:554/h264 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! matroskamux ! filesink location= file.mkv
```

It works.

Now I add shared memory:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.88.248:554/h264 ! shmsink socket-path=/tmp/foo shm-size=2000000
```

And

```
gst-launch-1.0 shmsrc socket-path=/tmp/foo ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! matroskamux ! filesink location=file.mkv
```

And I get message:

> Input buffers need to have RTP caps set on them.

Ok, I write

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.88.248:554/h264 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264" ! shmsink socket-path=/tmp/foo shm-size=2000000
```

And I get this message again.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the caps after shmsrc, for example following is my receiving pipeline:

> gst-launch-1.0 -v  rtspsrc
>   location=rtsp://192.168.1.150:8554/VBoxVideo  ! shmsink
>   socket-path=/tmp/foo shm-size=2000000 wait-for-connection=false

You have to note down the caps from the above shmsink, following are my caps for shmsink:

> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstShmSink:shmsink0.GstPad:sink: caps =
>   "application/x-rtp\,\ media\=(string)video\,\ payload\=(int)96\,\
>   clock-rate\=(int)90000\,\ encoding-name\=(string)H264\,\
>   packetization-mode\=(string)1\,\
>   profile-level-id\=(string)64002a\,\
>   sprop-parameter-sets\=(string)\"J2QAKqwbKgHgCJ+WEAAAPoAADqYOAAEZABGQve6wgA\\=\\=\\,KP4Briw\\=\"\,\
>   a-tool\=(string)GStreamer\,\ a-type\=(string)broadcast\,\
>   a-framerate\=(string)30\,\ a-ts-refclk\=(string)local\,\
>   a-mediaclk\=(string)sender\,\ ssrc\=(uint)4083957277\,\
>   clock-base\=(uint)1018840792\,\ seqnum-base\=(uint)13685\,\
>   npt-start\=(guint64)0\,\ play-speed\=(double)1\,\
>   play-scale\=(double)1"

Now, to use shmsrc,

> gst-launch-1.0 -vm shmsrc socket-path=/tmp/foo do-timestamp=true is-live=true
>   num-buffers=1000 !
>   "application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,payload=(int)96,packetization-mode=(string)1" ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=file.mp4

Note: I have set the caps from the above, also note I have set um-buffers=1000 as I am using mp4mux, and I need to send and eos for the file to play.

So in your case:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location=rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.88.248:554/h264 ! shmsink socket-path=/tmp/foo shm-size=2000000
```

Note down the caps from the pipeline for shmsink0, and later use it in your pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 shmsrc socket-path=/tmp/foo is-live=true num-buffers=1000 ! caps ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=file.mp4
```

Comment: Hi, thank you.

But now I got an error:
(gst-launch-1.0:15374): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_segment_to_running_time: assertion 'segment->format == format' failed

My pipeline is:
gst-launch-1.0 shmsrc socket-path=/tmp/foo is-live=true ! "application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,payload=(int)99,packetization-mode=(string)1" ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! matroskamux ! filesink location=file.mkv

Comment: add do-timestamp=true for shmsrc element.